# RSA C# encryption with public key to use with PHP openssl_private_decrypt(): Chilkat, BouncyCastle, RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, bouncycastle, chilkat

i'm trying to encrypt the string in C# application for it to be decrypted on PHP side with openssl_private_decrypt().
the initial public key that i'm trying to decrypt with is obtained from within PHP's openssl_pkey_get_details($privateKey);
talking ahead, i am able to do it using chilkat, but it doesn't work in monotouch under iOS so it is useless for me (and it costs pretty much too).
there is code sample how i'm doing it:

```
void TestEncryption(string publicKey, string data)
{
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

        //by using chilkat
        var key = new Chilkat.PublicKey();
        var result = key.LoadOpenSslPem(publicKey);
        var ck = new Chilkat.Rsa();
        ck.UnlockComponent("blablabla");
        var keyXml = key.GetXml();
        ck.ImportPublicKey(keyXml);
        var ckBytes = ck.EncryptBytes(bytes, false);

        //by using BouncyCastle
        Object obj;
        using (TextReader sr = new StringReader(publicKey))
        {
            PemReader pem = new PemReader(sr);
            obj = pem.ReadObject();               
        }
        var par = obj as Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.RsaKeyParameters;
        RsaEngine e = new RsaEngine();
        e.Init(true, par);           
        var bcBytes = e.ProcessBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        //RSACryptoServiceProvider. don't know exectly how to initialize it, one way that must work i think is from chilkat's xml, just to test
        RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);
        csp.FromXmlString(keyXml);

        //also tryed to initialize like this:
        //var pp = csp.ExportParameters(false);
        //pp.Modulus = byteKey; //this one is publicKey, stripped from --begin-- and --end-- sections and encoded from base64 to byte array (162 bytes)
        //csp.ImportParameters(pp);
        //
        //or if i do
        //var pp = new RSAParameters();
        //pp.Exponent = Convert.FromBase64String("AQAB");
        //pp.Exponent array is the same: {1, 0, 1};

        var cspBytes = csp.Encrypt(bytes, false); //or (bytes, true), doesn't matter           

        //this function sends request to php and returns result of decryption attempt         
        Debug.WriteLine(ExecRequest(ckBytes));
        Debug.WriteLine(ExecRequest(bcBytes));
        Debug.WriteLine(ExecRequest(cspBytes));
}
```

the output is:

```
success
decryption failed
decryption failed
```

what am i missing?

Comment: -1 and put on hold? lol. what i'm asking is obvious: how to encrypt data with RSA within the C# application for this data to be decrypted with PHP's openssl_private_decrypt(). and not use chilkat for that. it is unclear why BouncyCastle's encryption won't work and how to get public key modulus for use with RSACryptoServiceProvider

Comment: There are two types of people that will usually want to help you. There are those that have done *exactly* what you're doing, and thus can easily spot "what is missing". And then there are those that would want to help you if they could grab some code that exhibits the problem, and work with that. Since the first category is usually *very* small, you want to aim for the second category, and thus you should always strive to provide 1) enough information about the problem that even those that aren't experts in that domain can understand it, and 2) a complete example with all the data necessary.

Comment: i'm sorry if some data is missing, but i tried to make code sample maximally approachable. i'e even rewrote my test sample to it be minimal in size, but still complete. pleas just tell me what information people from second category might be missing. what necessary data? this code could be tested having public and private keys generated within PHP, any c# IDE and bouncy castle library. http://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/products/visual-studio-express-vs http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/

Comment: i have seen many questions that are more general or incomplete, still, no one carps. may be the thing is, those questions are just simpler to answer. idk. anyway, i've found adhoc solution. i don't like it much, but it works. either way, i just wanna know how to  solve the task by using just bouncy castle, or just with standart .NET's RSACryptoServiceProvider (and whatever it may need)

Comment: but the thing is, from my observations, despite of the first category is small, as you say, the vast majority of narrow questions is answered by very it. so, the main task of person who asks is to make the question clear for that first category, people that already know something concerning the subject. obviously, very small number of people will spoil their time solving the problem, they even never stucked upon closely and that is not theoretic or fundamental, but rather special in it appliance. correct me if i'm wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, after doing some shamanic dances with tambourine i've come to somewhat-satisfying solution.
please hold in mind, that it is all done in context of working with PHP's openssl_private_decrypt() function.

so i got next:

1. encryption of BouncyCastle just doing it not right
2. i don't know how to get modulus out of private key to use it with RSACryptoServiceProvider
3. why not try to use BouncyCastle's key data and initialize RSACryptoServiceProvider

   ```
   Object obj;
   using (TextReader sr = new StringReader(publicKey))
   {
       PemReader pem = new PemReader(sr);
       obj = pem.ReadObject();               
   }
   var par = obj as Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.RsaKeyParameters;

   RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);        
   //var pp = csp.ExportParameters(false); //works on native .NET, doesn't work on monotouch
   var pp = new RSAParameters();
   pp.Modulus = par.Modulus.ToByteArrayUnsigned(); //doesn't work with ToByteArray()
   pp.Exponent = par.Exponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned();                          
   csp.ImportParameters(pp);
   var cspBytes = csp.Encrypt(bytes, false);
   ```

actually, it is strange that i've came up with solution at all, cuz of these niceties.
i hope it would be helpful for someone someday.